# Checking whether something is within a radius in order to alert an enemy in a Unity 2D game using 'Physics.OverlapSphere'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title describes I am currently experiencing an issue where 'Physics.OverlapSphere' isnt putting anything into the array. I feel as if it is a very simple error but it  is something I cannot find.

Below is the code that I wrote and what I expected was that when the player went within the radius the Phyhsics.OverlapSphere would add to the array where it would then trigger the rest of the checks.

```
public class EnemyFieldOfView : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float efovRadius = 4f;
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public float efovAngle = 45f;

    public GameObject playerSprite;
    public bool alerted;

    public LayerMask playerMask;
    public LayerMask objectMask;

    public Collider[] playerSearch;


    public void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(searchRoutine());
    }

    public IEnumerator searchRoutine()
    {
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);

        while (true)
        {
            yield return wait;
            Searching();
        }
    }

    public void Searching()
    {
        playerSearch = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, efovRadius, playerMask);
        if (playerSearch.Length != 0)
        {
            Transform enemyTarget = playerSearch[0].transform;
            Vector2 targetDirection = (enemyTarget.position - transform.position).normalized;

            Debug.Log("In fov circle");

            if (Vector3.Angle(enemySprite.transform.up, targetDirection) < efovAngle / 2)
            {
                float distanceBetween = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemyTarget.position); 
                if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, targetDirection, distanceBetween, objectMask))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Alerted");
                    alerted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    alerted = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alerted = false;
            }
        }
        if (alerted == true)
        {
            alerted = false;
        }
    }
'''
```

Comment: You can try and execute the "Searching()" method inside the FixedUpdate() loop instead of running it through a coroutine in the Start() method

Comment: @PavlosMavris +1 .. or alternatively use `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate ();` .. though I see no reason why one would prefer the Coroutine over `FixedUpdate` ;) .. or you could simply use a dedicated Sphere Collider Trigger and use `OnTriggerEnter`/`OnTriggerExit` .. or if there is only one player anyway you could as well simply check via the distance ^^

Comment: For the second inner check you might rather simply use a [`Physics.LineCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html) which takes a start and endpoint instead of a ray and distance ;)

Comment: And if this is a 2D game .. are you using 2D colliders or 3D colliders? If 2D than `Physics` is the wrong engine and you rather want to use a `Physics2D.OverlapCircle`

Comment: Also in general if you are only interested in a single result anyway you might want to rather use the [non-alloc versions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc.html) with a single element array as input. Note that in general there is no guaranteed order of results and the first/only element is not necessarily the closest / best fit => you should probably run your checks against all hits and then sort them by the closest and smallest angle and take that as the target

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a 3D game, the player should have at least one primitive collider or a mesh collider with convex ticked. Non-convex MeshColliders will not work with this. If the game is 2D ("enemySprite") then you're better off using Physics2D.OverlapCircle or sth. And although Z-axis does not truly matter with it, you can still define min/max depth for 2D setups where layers have some distance between them on Z-axis.

Also minor nitpick, you don't have to check:

```cs
if(alerted == true)
{
   alerted = false
}
```

just do `csharp alerted = false;`. Even if alerted is false, it'll get assigned twice.

Better yet, do the following:

```cs
public void Searching()
{
    alerted = false;
    playerSearch = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, efovRadius, playerMask);
    if (playerSearch.Length != 0)
    {
        Transform enemyTarget = playerSearch[0].transform;
        Vector2 targetDirection = (enemyTarget.position - transform.position).normalized;

        Debug.Log("In fov circle");

        if (Vector3.Angle(enemySprite.transform.up, targetDirection) < efovAngle / 2)
        {
            float distanceBetween = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemyTarget.position); 
            if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, targetDirection, distanceBetween, objectMask))
            {
                Debug.Log("Alerted");
                alerted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since Searching does not yield control, it will all be processed, therefore if you still have someone within the range, it'll keep alerted set to true.